# AzureDevops - capture variable value from the branch name

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Hi guys I'm working in tryin to get a number in the branch name, for example if I have the branch: test_branch.$someNumber
I want to put that someNumber into a variable

trigger:

- master
- "test_branch.*"

${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'test_branch') }}:

releaseMinorVersion: Don't know what use here, I tried differents options but didn't work

version: 5.$(releaseMinorVersion).$(Build.BuildId)

I tried with regular expression but that didn't work

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check my answer below? If it could help resolve your issue, you may consider accepting the answer. Thx.

Comment: Hi @Elias Bucci, may I know if by any chance you have tested with my suggestion below. If the answer works for you, you may consider [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), which may help others with similar concerns. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you would like to extract the `number` from the name of the pipeline's triggering branch and use the `number` to define the variable `releaseMinorVersion` as a part of `version`. For this, you may consider using [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#split) function which is also one of the [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) of a YAML pipeline. Kindly refer to the sample below.

```
trigger:
- master
- test_Branch.*

variables:
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'test_branch') }}:
    releaseMinorVersion: ${{ split(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], '.')[1] }}
  ${{ else }}:
    releaseMinorVersion: 0
  version: 5.$(releaseMinorVersion).$(Build.BuildId)

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Source Branch Name is $(Build.SourceBranchName)"
      echo "Version is $(version)"
```

[image]

Hope the answer can help.